# Reverse contains() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, contains

I'm new to laravel,
I'm trying to get a row from a table according to it's Many-to-Many relationship with another table.

You know when you pass multiple ids in `contain()` to check if they have relationship with that row or not, like this:

```
$row->contains([4,6,9]);
```

i want to reverse this, where i can use the ids `[4,6,9]` to get any row from the other table linked with them.

Comment: You can use model relationships between your database tables to establish the relationships and call them quite easily. Do you have any models set up yet?

Comment: yes i have all my models set up with belongsToMany relationship between the two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this two models: `User` and `Role` that makes many-to-many relationship.

If you defined your relationships properly:

```
/** User.php */

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

-

```
/** Role.php */

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Then you could use the relationship to accomplish what you are trying to do.

From the related object:

```
$user = User::find(1);

// getting all the roles attached with a user:
$roles = $user->roles;

// getting all the roles attached with a user that has certain ids:
$roles = $user->roles()->whereIn('id', [2, 4, 6])->get();
```

Also, you could find your desired related model using the collection instance that return the relationship:

```
$user = User::find(1);

// getting all the roles attached with a user:
$roles = $user->roles;

// getting a specific role attached to a user:
$specific_role = $roles->where('id', 6)->first();
```

Comment: what if i need the roles from user that have specific permission ids?

Comment: @AbdallahMekawy this will depend on how you have structured your tables. I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: $user->roles()->with('permissions',function($q){
            $q->whereIn('id', [2, 4, 6]);
            })->get();

Comment: can i do it like this?

Comment: @AbdallahMekawy If your `Role` model has the `permissions()` relationship, yes you can.